# separate the segments of characters and numbers with a given separator of your choice from a given string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a function that takes two strings as input and returns a tuple containing the extracted segments of characters and numbers.
like:

```
string_to_parse = 'Copenhagen hosted Cop -09 summit at Bella Centre in 2009 , which was attended by delegates from more than 100 countries.'
separator = '_'
tuple_to_be_returned = ('CopenhagenhostedCop_summitatBellaCentrein_whichwasattendedbydelegatesfrommorethan_countries','09 _2009_100')
```

anyone has any ideas that how could I approach this?
any ideas would be great!
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

this is a lil yucky and kinda spaghetti code but it works, and it would be a good exercise to refactor this function and make it neater.  Good luck!!

```
def separate(string, separator):
    words = []
    nums = []
    for word in string.split(" "):
        if word.isnumeric():
            nums.append(word)
            string = string.replace(word, separator, 1)
        else:
            words.append(word)

    return "".join(map(lambda s: s if s.isalpha() or s == separator else "", "".join(string.split(" ")))), separator.join(nums)
```

Comment: Thank you so much mate, I will give it a try!!

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
import re

def function (strng):

    pattern = r'\-?(\d+)\s?\,?'
    results = re.findall(pattern, strng)

    nums = ['_' + vals for vals in results]
    nums = ' '.join(nums)




    values = r'\1\2'
    new =re.sub(pattern, '_', strng)
    new = new.split()
    return (''.join(new)) , (str(nums))
```